# TextView hieght = wrap_content is not working

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, textview, android-linearlayout

I have a `LinearLayout` which contains a single `TextView` :

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/addTaskDescriptionLLId"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/descriptionTextViewId"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxHeight="150dp"
                    android:hint="@string/abcd"
                    android:textColor="#A2A2A2"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

I've also added a condition in java file and the condition is if the `TextView` has some text during opening the activity then it will be visible otherwise I used `descriptionTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Then I put some text in this `textView` by opening a dialog and `onConfirm` (clicking positive button of dialog) I did the following:

```java
    @Override
    public void onConfirm(String description) {
        this.description = description;    //the string that I write in dialog
        descriptionLL.removeAllViews();    //parent LineanLayout of TextView
        descriptionLL.addView(descriptionTextView);
        descriptionTextView.setText(description);
        descriptionTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

But the TextView height doesn't remain wrap_content as I mentioned in xml file.
I've also tried :

```java
descriptionTextView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

that also no working..Any solution?

Comment: Why are you removing and re-adding the `TextView`?

Comment: because I've to replace the `TextView` (if empty) with a `addTextButton`. And I don't want an `EditText` here.

Comment: OK. I'm not sure how an `EditText` might help, though. What does the height end up being, exactly?

Comment: yes, height remains `match_parent`.

Comment: How are you determining that? I mean, are you checking the value in its `LayoutParams`? Or are you just going by visual behavior? In either case, we're likely going to need a [mcve].

Comment: OK, problem solved. I put a hint in `TextView`. And that was the problem. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the hint that you've specified in `xml` is causing the problem. Remove it, it might solve.